# Where i can find the add() function for order $result = $order->add() in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

In prestashop, i am trying to **debug add()** which is used in

```
/website.com/override/classes/PaymentModule.php
```

As

```
 $result = $order->add();
```

I have searched this in prestashop directory but do not able to get it.

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

It is in classes/ObjectModel.php which is inherited by almost all others.